# Out generic parameters with types only known at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I have an interface:

```
public interface IOut<T>
{
    void Get(out T output);
}
```

and a class that implements it:

```
public class Impl : IOut<string>, IOut<int>{
    public void Get(out string output) { output = "string"; }
    public void Get(out int output) { output = 12; }
}
```

I can do the following just fine:

```
public static void Main()
{
    dynamic dImpl = new Impl();

    string sOutput;
    int iOutput;

    dImpl.Get(out sOutput);
    dImpl.Get(out iOutput);

    Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
    Console.WriteLine(iOutput);
}
```

My problem is that I only know the type I need to *get* at runtime, so how I *want* to call my `Get` code is like so:

```
public static void Main()
{
    dynamic dImpl = new Impl();

    var t = typeof(string);
    t output;
    dImpl.Get(out output);

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Now, I know this *won't* work, and I've tried reflectively performing a Cast:

```
public static T Cast<T>(object o) { return (T) o; }
```

but I don't have an object to cast, I only have a `Type`. I've tried Defaults:

```
public static T Default<T>() { return default(T); }
```

but the default for things like `string` etc is null, and when invoking the method via reflection:

```
var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Default").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
var defaulted = method.Invoke(null, null);
```

`defaulted` is going to be null, and when calling `dImpl.Get(out defaulted)` the runtime is unsure of which overload to use.

So, what I'm looking for is either:
a) someway to do this using the current interface setup [preferred]
b) a different way to achieve the goals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the method to invoke from the interface type instead of the implementing type:

```
object[] parameters = new object[] { null };
Type typeParam = typeof(string);
Type ifaceType = typeof(IOut<>).MakeGenericType(typeParam);
MethodInfo method = ifaceType.GetMethod("Get");

var impl = new Impl();
method.Invoke(impl, parameters);

object outParam = parameters[0];
```

Comment: That's great, I'd not thought about going at it that way.

Comment: where does `impl` in `method.Invoke(impl, parameters)` come from?

Comment: @bflemi3 - It's just meant to be an instance of the `Impl` class. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type of `output` until runtime, you can't declare a strongly-typed instance of it in C#.

If you can make the calling logic ( `Main` in your example ) generic on `T` too, that would work - but this only defers your problem.

The other option is to declare `output` as a base class or interface and restrict the generic `T` to that. Using `object` as the base class might work for you - depends on what you want to do with it.